# Process Pledges Error Invalid Criteria For IN

Tags: wordpress, pledges

CiviCRM v5.48.2, WordPress v 5.9.3

I have a cron running as follows:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxx -e Job -a execute`

```
Entity: Job Action: process_pledge
Summary
Finished execution of Process Pledges with result: Failure, Error message: invalid criteria for IN
Details

Parameters raw (from db settings): 
send_reminders=1

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:14:"send_reminders";s:1:"1";}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Process Pledges with result: Failure, Error message: invalid criteria for IN
```

Comment: Is there more detail in the civicrm log file? (not the job log)

Comment: Too long to add. Seems to be starting here: May 04 23:18:27 [info] inactive contribution page access attempted - page number 2 May 04 23:18:27 [error] $Fatal Error Details = array:3 [ "message" => "The page you requested is currently unavailable." "code" => null "exception" => CRM_Contribute_Exception_InactiveContributionPageException

Comment: Here is the entire error which tends to repeat itself: pastebin.com/embed_iframe/BncdZcrF

Comment: @Aidan did you need more info to examine? Thanks!

Comment: That's a different error - one caused by a user trying to access an inactive contribution page from the WP site.  The relevant section of your logfile should include 'invalid criteria for IN'